# SSL handshake failure to call Tibco BW6 secured API from WSO2 ESB proxy service

Tags: ssl, https, tibco, wso2-esb

I have created a proxy service in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and I am calling a secured https API which is made in Tibco BW6. This API is secured with SSL security.
When I send my message from proxy service to Tibco API, I get SSL hand shake problem.
Also I have imported a client.cer certificate in my jks carbon key store on my WSO2 ESB but still I am unable to send my message on API. 
Note: I have no experience about SSL

> ERROR IN LOGS:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

Answer (score 0):

You can export the server certificate via the browser. Then import it into
the client-truststore.jks. For trouble shooting you may have to do an SSL debug and my blog post [1] will help you doing this.

You can follow the following steps to import your server certificate into wso2esb client’s keystore as follows:

- Go to backend service in your browser, and then click the HTTPS trust
  icon on the address bar (e.g., the padlock next to the URL in
  Firefox).
- View the certificate details (the steps vary by browser) and then
  export the trust certificate to the file system.
- Use the ESB Management Console or the following command to import
  that certificate into the ESB client keystore. keytool -importcert
  -file  -keystore /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -alias
  "your-alias"
- Restart the server.

Happy coding!

[1] http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2014/11/ssl-debugging-in-wso2-esb.html